# Maintain URLs in single page application?

Tags: ajax, url, single-page-application

I am new to SPA and developing my first SPA website. I want to know what are the tools/technics to change the URLs when making Ajax requests.

I could do this hash/hashbangs but I am looking for a solution without hashbangs, exactly how its done on Twitter website.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to do it without the hash, you will need server-side support.

There is a pretty detailed discussion about this on the [Spine Routing](http://spinejs.com/docs/routing) page (Spine is a SPA MVC framework); go down to **HTML5 History**. The information there is not specific to Spine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few out there but the 2 most popular are:

### Historyjs

[Historyjs](http://balupton.github.com/history.js) is very barebones but gives you complete controll over the history stack

### Sammyjs

[Sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org/) does the same things as historyjs but sammy does a lot more. It listens to the window.location and if it changes it can call methods based off it changing. This is good if you want to generate routes based off anchor links. `<a href="#somepage">goto somepage</a>`.  It does a lot more also which allows you to create route dictionaries of what js methods to call for certain routes.